# Tzadikkim hands above the waist?

Tags: tzaddikim

The Tzaddikim used to always keep their hands above their waists. I can understand how this was done when all you wore was a robe and sandals, but how did men like the Chofetz Chaim do it when they wore pants? How'd they get dressed and go to the bathroom?

Edit: The Gemara says the Rebbe's hands never went below his waist and the Rambam says that it's a righteous thing to do. When you look at pictures and videos of the Chofetz Chaim, his hands are never below his waist.

Comment: For the record, there are all of like 3 pictures of the Chofetz Chaim and about 30 seconds of video. I don't know how much of a proof we could bring from his everyday actions from those sources alone.

Comment: Adding more specific citations to the Rambam and Talmud would further improve your question.

Comment: How would a person wash like this?

Comment: @dude that's another question...

Comment: "I can understand how this was done when all you wore was a robe and sandals": if you can understand how they tied their sandals, then what's hard to understand about how they put on pants?

Comment: Maybe it means "never when it was avoidable", but not  when getting dressed going to bathroom.